# How to call a XAML code in NavigationPage.SetTitleView in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that uses a custom navigation title view only for Android. For now my title view is defined in my template constructor like below:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(InnerContent))]
public partial class ContentCustomTitleView : ContentPage
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty InnerContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InnerContent), typeof(View), typeof(ContentCustomTitleView));
    public static readonly BindableProperty PageTitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PageTitle), typeof(string), typeof(Label), default(string), BindingMode.OneWay);

    public View InnerContent
    {
        get => (View)this.GetValue(InnerContentProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value);
    }

    public string PageTitle
    {
        get
        {
            var value = (string)GetValue(PageTitleProperty);
            return value;
        }
        set => SetValue(PageTitleProperty, value);
    }

    public ContentCustomTitleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == "Android")
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, SetBackView());
        }
    }

    StackLayout SetBackView()
    {
        StackLayout backButton = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                new Label {
                    Text = "\u25C3",
                    FontSize = 25,
                }
            },
            Padding = new Thickness(5, 0, 20, 0),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Orange
        };

        var tabEvent = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tabEvent.Tapped += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { Navigation.PopAsync(); };
        backButton.GestureRecognizers.Add(tabEvent);

        Label pageTitle = new Label()
        {
            FontSize = 14,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        };
        pageTitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(path: "PageTitle", source: this));

        StackLayout backView = new StackLayout
        { 
            Children = 
            {
                backButton,
                pageTitle
            },
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        };

        return backView;
    }

}
```

And then I use this code in XAML:

```
<t:ContentCustomTitleView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             x:Class="MyProject.Details"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             PageTitle="Application Details">
            <!-- more code here -->
</t:ContentCustomTitleView>
```

What I would like to do is create my title view template in a separate xaml file and just call that template in `NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, );` and pass the `PageTitle` property to that title view template. Is this possible? I've been stuck on this dilemma for days.

**Edits:**

Here is what I have so far. In XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="MyProject.TitleViewTemplate"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackLayout x:Name="backButton" Padding="5,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start">
        <Label Text="&#x25c3;" FontSize="25"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="pageTitle" FontSize="14"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In C#:

```
public partial class TitleViewTemplate : StackLayout
{
   public TitleViewTemplate()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   public StackLayout SetBackView(EventHandler backButtonClicked)
   {
      var tabEvent = new TapGestureRecognizer();
      tabEvent.Tapped += backButtonClicked;
      backButton.GestureRecognizers.Add(tabEvent);

      pageTitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(path: "PageTitle", source: this));

      return this;
   }
}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to call it inside my `ContentCustomTitleView` like this:

```
// more code here
public ContentCustomTitleView()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   BindingContext = this;
   tv = new TitleViewTemplate();
   if (Device.RuntimePlatform == "Android")
   {
      NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
      NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, tv.SetBackView(GoBack));
    }
 }
 /// more code here
 void GoBack(object o, EventArgs e) { Navigation.PopAsync() };
```

This works but not 100%. I am able to display the XAML alright but I can't get the `PageTitle` value from the `TitleViewTemplate`. Can anyone point me to the right direction here? Maybe I'm missing some bindings or something?

Comment: What you want is basically a method that you can call to change your Nav bar title?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this :

```
  StackLayout titleView = tv.SetBackView(GoBack);
  Label label = titleView.FindByName<Label>("pageTitle");
  string titleText = label.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  pageTitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(path: "PageTitle", source: this));
```

This looks good to me, Have you tried reordering your code and setting the page title when the constructor of your custom view is called.?
i.e. with initializing Component for the custom view.